# Specify columns for PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, laravel-4

I have a table with a following columns (more than 2) in my database:
1. id
2. name
3. email

I am trying to fetch key value pairs using PDO by fetching the fetchMode to `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR` and specifying columns `id` and `name` ***which works just fine***

But when i try to specify `name` and `email` as the desired columns i get the result set but the `key` is not `name` but usual `numeric zero based indexes`

`0 => some@email.com`

Why?

BTW i am using laravel, here is my code:

```
$users = new User;
$users->getConnection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
return $users::get(array('name','email'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result by using:

```
User::lists('email', 'name');
```