# Laravel strange PDO fetchMode issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, laravel-4

This works and shows the result set:

```
$mainFeatures = new Mainfeature;
$mainFeatures->getConnection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
$main = $mainFeatures::get(array('id','data'))->toArray();
dd($main);
```

But if i try to return with the result set:

```
return View::make('orders.create')
    ->with('features', Feature::with('Subfeature')->get()->toArray())
    ->with('mainFeatures', $main);
```

It gives an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR fetch mode requires the result set to contain extactly 2 columns. (SQL: select * from `features`) (Bindings: array ( ))
```

Not sure from where `select * from features` comes in...

Comment: Not used Laravel before, but `get()` would surely produce the `SELECT *`, while `get(array('id','data'))` (as in your first example) would surely produce `SELECT id, data`, which is what you want for `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`

Comment: @Clive want to have a look at another issues i am having with PDO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20434522/specify-columns-for-pdofetch-key-pair Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed that i was changing the fetch mode for the `connection` and not just the `class Mainfeature`. So i had to reset it.

```
$mainFeatures = new Mainfeature;
    $mainFeatures->getConnection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
    $main = $mainFeatures::get(array('id','data'))->toArray();
    //dd($h);
    //dd($main);

    $features = new Feature;
    $features->getConnection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

    return View::make('orders.create')
        ->with('features', $features::with('Subfeature')->get()->toArray())
        ->with('mainFeatures', $main);
```

Credit goes to Clive for pointing me in the right direction.